# Is there a way around mongo $lookup from overwritten subdocument

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I've been banging my head against this one for a while. MongoDB experience is limited/outdated, but I am performing a `$lookup`, which is joining how I would like it to. However, the `as` is overwriting my entire subdocument. I read in the docs that this is the behaviour, but what I am trying to do is perform a lookup using a nested a reference, which is working, but then setting the join-ing data to that reference (or at least in that sub document) along with the existing data that is within the sub document.

I also have a complication that this logic - for legitmate reasons - is not running off of `Id`

A mocked up example command below :

```
db.getCollection('agendas').aggregate([
        {
          $match: {
            'book.author._id': ObjectId('author-id')
          }
        },
        {
          $lookup:
          {
            from: 'author',
            // an array of keys e.g. ['penguin', 'puffin']
            localField: 'book.author.publishers',
            foreignField: 'pub_key',
            as: 'book.author.publishers'
          }
        },
])
```

**Output :**

```
{
    book: {
        name: 'The Bible',
        author: {
            publishers: [
                ...allJoinedPublishersData
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

So my issue is that the lookup works, but it's wiping out the whole author object and all the data at the nested levels - I've wrestled with merging and grouping and haven't managed to get this to work. What would be an appropriate command to use? Effectively to merge the existing document with the joined data. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So `$lookup` will create a new field or overwrites an existing field with output from `as`. When you've `as: 'book.author.publishers'` it basically tries to create a field named **book** with is having **author** as sub-doc & **publishers** as sub-doc to author. Since `$lookup` is able to find **book** field in actual doc - it will replace book field with output of lookup. So instead of that you can try like below :

```
[
    {
        $match: {
            'book.author._id': ObjectId('author-id')
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup:
        {
            from: 'author',
            // an array of keys e.g. ['penguin', 'puffin']
            localField: 'book.author.publishers',
            foreignField: 'pub_key',
            as: 'publishers' // write it to a field named publishers
        }
    },
    { $addFields: { 'book.author.publishers': '$publishers' } }, // Now overwrite your actual 'book.author.publishers' like this
    { $project: { publishers: 0 } } // Remove the unnecessary field publishers
]
```

**Note :** You can avoid two stages i.e; `$addFields` & `$project` by using `$project` directly instead of addFields but it all depends on requirement & your document structure.